# Program will not loop back until correct

Tags: java

```
/*Do method to continually ask for correct spelled day until it matches a valid input */
do {   
    System.out.print('\n' + "What is the current Day (Monday-Sunday): ");
    currentDay = stdIn.nextLine();
}while (!(currentDay.equals("Sunday") || currentDay.equals("Monday") || 
          currentDay.equals("Tuesday") || currentDay.equals("Wednesday") ||
          currentDay.equals("Thursday") || currentDay.equals("Friday") || 
          currentDay.equals("Saturday")));

if(!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight)){
    System.out.println("Today isn't your day for a flight, keep cheching");
}

while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight));

System.out.print("What is the current hour (Military time): ");
int currentHour = stdIn.nextInt();

int time = (hourOfFlight - currentHour);
System.out.println('\n' + "You have " + time + " hours to go.");
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this. Im a newbie and the whole program runs fine if the days our correct but doesnt if days dont match.

Comment: The while loop with an empty body is very fishy. Could this be caused by indentation problems? Do you have warnings turned on in your IDE?

Comment: Where did I go wrong? I think at the IF statement it falls apart.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I obviously didn't upload the whole code. What I am trying to do is if dayofflight doesnt not match current day then i want it to drop end and go to command prompt

Comment: What's the idea behind line `while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight));`?

Answer (score 1):

Your second `while` will either do nothing or loop infinitely.

To check this you can step through the code in your debugger.

```
while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight));
```

is the same as

```
while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight)) {
   // nothing changes so loop forever
}
```

What you may have intended is to have a second `do/while` loop where this is the end.

Comment: I suggest using the debugger in your IDE to step through the code so you can see what each line of code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your second `while`:

```
while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight));
```

It is like [Peter Lawyrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) said, "you may have intended to have a second do/while loop where this is the end". The beginning of this second do/while is most  likely  outside of the first, thus encapsulating the first and executing it until `currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight)` returns  true:

```
do { // Beginning
    do {
        System.out.print('\n' + "What is the current Day (Monday-Sunday): ");
        currentDay = stdIn.nextLine();
    } while (!(currentDay.equals("Sunday") || currentDay.equals("Monday") || currentDay.equals("Tuesday")
            || currentDay.equals("Wednesday") || currentDay.equals("Thursday") || currentDay.equals("Friday")
            || currentDay.equals("Saturday")));

    if (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight)) {
        System.out.println("Today isn't your day for a flight, keep cheching");
        // Don't you mean "keep checking"?
    }

} while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight)); // End

System.out.print("What is the current hour (Military time): ");
int currentHour = stdIn.nextInt();

int time = (hourOfFlight - currentHour);
System.out.println('\n' + "You have " + time + " hours to go.");
```

On a side note, you might want to change `currentDay#equals` to `currentDay#equalsIgnoreCase` and `System#print` to `System#println`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String currentDay,dayOfFlight="Monday";
    int hourOfFlight=10;
    do {   
         System.out.print('\n' + "What is the current Day (Monday-Sunday): ");
         currentDay = reader.nextLine();


        if(!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight)){
          System.out.println("Today isn't your day for a flight, keep cheching");
         }
    }

    while (!currentDay.equals(dayOfFlight));

        System.out.print("What is the current hour (Military time): ");
        int currentHour = reader.nextInt();

        int time = (hourOfFlight - currentHour);
        System.out.println('\n' + "You have " + time + " hours to go.");
```

You doesn't need to use that while loop to check until correct. (if that is what you are trying to achieve.)